# Dynamic select option using select2 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

In my page, I have one select option using select2 and a button to dynamic add new select option to the page. But I have a problem with new control that is created dynamically by the button, I can't select it anymore like the original control. I'm still trying to solve it but it could be great if you give me a hand, thank in advance!

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery( function( $ )
 {
  var $body = $( 'body' );

  $( '.sl-select' ).select2();

  $body.on( 'click', '.add-report', function()
  {
   var $this = $( this ),
    $clone = $this.siblings( '.report:last' ).clone();

   $clone.insertBefore( $this );
  } );
 } );
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="report">
  <select class="sl-select">
   <option value="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2">option 2</option>
   <option value="3">option 3</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <button class="add-report">Add Report</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh256tem/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution will be to clone the first element before, then after each append we reinitiate the select2 plugin

```
var $body = $( 'body' );
var $clone = '<div class="report"><select class="sl-select"><option value="1">option 1</option><option value="2">option 2</option><option value="3">option 3</option></select></div>'
    $( '.sl-select' ).select2();

    $body.on( 'click', '.add-report', function()
    {

      var $this = $( this );
    $body.prepend($clone);


    $( '.sl-select:first').select2();
    } );
```

Comment: thank you for your helping but it only works when you click `.add-report` first time, from the second time, the controls aren't working.

Comment: yes, the new control is working but the previous controls stop working

Comment: I can't add more than 2 controls

Comment: strange with clone you can only append it on time, i updated my code, this should work ,but this doesn't use clone

Comment: thank you, it's working, but we have to put all html content into a javascript variable, it's very inconvenience if it's long

Comment: use ajax if is to long